# C# how can I get a count of Json with several levels

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, datacontractjsonserializer, httpresponsemessage

I have a json like this one that comes from an api. 
I´m using oauth2 so i got the token, then I request the data.
I want to count the name inside resources, to know how many are.

```
{
  "startDate": "2019-06-23T16:07:21.205Z",
  "endDate": "2019-07-24T16:07:21.205Z",
  "status": "Complete",
  "usages": [
    {
      "name": "PureCloud Edge Virtual Usage",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "Edge01-VM-GNS-DemoSite01 (1f279086-a6be-4a21-ab7a-2bb1ae703fa0)",
          "date": "2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "329ad5ae-e3a3-4371-9684-13dcb6542e11",
          "date": "2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z"
        },        
        {
          "name": "e5796741-bd63-4b8e-9837-4afb95bb0c09",
          "date": "2019-07-24T09:00:28.034Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PureCloud for SmartVideo Add-On Concurrent",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "jpizarro@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "jaguilera@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },        
        {
          "name": "dcortes@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PureCloud 3 Concurrent User Usage",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "jpizarro@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "jaguilera@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },       
        {
          "name": "dcortes@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PureCloud Skype for Business WebSDK",
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "jpizarro@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },
        {
          "name": "jaguilera@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-06-25T04:54:17.662Z"
        },      
        {
          "name": "dcortes@gns.com.co",
          "date": "2019-07-15T15:06:09.203Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "selfUri": "/api/v2/billing/reports/billableusage"
}
```

This are the classes that i use.

```
   public class Resources
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Usages
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public IList<Resources> resources { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public IList<Usages> usages { get; set; }
        public string selfUri { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the function that I use, it receives the url and the token and it gets the data:

```
static async Task<int> GetNamesCount(string theUrl, string theToken)        
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Records records = new Records();                
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(theUrl);               
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", theToken);

                try
                {

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(theUrl);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
                    records = (Records)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Records)).ReadObject(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
```

I´ve tried, but I can only count the first two levels. I´ve searched but I can´t use [1] or records.usages["resources"].
What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to calculate the count of names for resources in `records` object?

Comment: What `name` parameters do you want to count?  The `usages[*].name` names, the `usages[*].resources[*].name` names, or both?  Also what do you want to do when a specific resource name is missing in the JSON? Is that a problem of concern?

Comment: The first, usages[*].name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**SelectMany**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) to fetch all *resources name* inside *usages list*, and use [**Count**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1) method to calculate the count of names insides resources :

```
int countNames = records.usages.SelectMany(x => x.resources.Select(y => y.name)).Count();
```

Or
Use [**Sum**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1) with `count`, like :

```
int countNames = records.usages.Sum(x => x.resources.Count(y => y.name != null));
```

If you want just the `count` of *names* inside `Usages`, you could use :

```
int countUsagesNames = records.usages.Count;
// or
int countUsagesNames = records.usages.Count(x => x.name != null);
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Cambié las clases por unas generadas automáticamente y usé tu consejo... funciona. Gracias